# Resize of columns in bootgrid

Tags: jquery, grid, boot

Since there are more number of columns in my bootgrid so the width of column has been reduced in such a way that data is visible partially. So i was thinking of having a facility of user can drag the column size to increase or decrease, or something like whenever user hover the column values and header the data should be visible as a tooltip.. Could you please whether this functionality is possible in bootgrid?

Answer (score 10):

Use the data-header-css-class attribute on the desired column and set it to your custom class having the desired width :)

```
<style>
.cgb-header-name {
    width: 50%;
}
</style>
...
<th data-column-id="name" data-header-css-class="cbg-header-name">Name</th>
...
```

You can also use the data-width attribute and set the value inline

```
...
<th data-column-id="name" data-width="70%">Name</th>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Work for me.

```
<th data-column-id="ID" data-type="numeric" data-width="30%">ID</th>
```

att.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What specifically solves the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the answer is no, no at least until the time of this writing.

The more the columns you have, the more their rows are downsized and the content hidden with ellipsis. 
No possibility to enlarge them by dragging or programmatically.

Also we tried creating "views" that only show a subset of columns, nonetheless still clipping occurs even with reasonably large columns, which obscures the readability of the contents.

You don't even have a tooltip to get to see what are the underlying contents, but you can implement this yourself.